# Сабмит формы с двумя submit?

Tags: javascript

форма:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="myform">

<select name="MySelect" onChange="::SUBMIT::mySecondSubmit">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="myFirstSubmit" />
<input type="submit" name="mySecondSubmit" />

</form>
```

Как засабмитить только конкретный `submit` при выборе значения из списка, в моем случае нужно засабмитить 2-й `submit`?

**Решение** ( да просто `id`-шник добавить и не парить себе мозги ).

```
<form action="" method="post" name="myform">

<select name="MySelect" onChange="javascript:var fSub  = document.getElementById('fSub'); fSub.click();">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" id="fSub" name="myFirstSubmit" />
<input type="submit" id="sSub" name="mySecondSubmit" />

</form>
```

Comment: form["myform"].myFirstSubmit.click() ?

Comment: А зачем это нужно? Может лучше использовать один сабмит, но в зависимости от переданных результатов по разному обрабатывать?

Просто как-то странно - разные сабмиты подразумевают разные действия над одними и теми же данными. А здесь получается - для разных данных - разные действия разными сабмитами.

Либо я чего-то не понял?

Comment: onChange="javascript:this.form['myform'].myFirstSubmit.click()" так? не получается.

Comment: @ВОРОН, ну надо так, система сложная.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/gz5EY/ на `jsfiddle` тоже не срабатывает.

Comment: Когда я слышу что-то вроде: "Так надо", "Сложная система", "По другому нельзя и другое не предлагать", то отчетливо понимаю, что человек сам себя загнал в угол из-за нехватки знаний и не желает даже представить, что можно найти нормальное решение задачи.

P.S. Добавьте третий submit - "Бог любит троицу", да и на перспективку пригодиться )))

Comment: Я никуда себя не загнал, мне так нужно.

Comment: > Я никуда себя не загнал, мне так нужно.

и для сравнения: 

>Когда я слышу что-то вроде: "Так надо", "Сложная система", "По другому нельзя и другое не предлагать", то отчетливо понимаю, что человек сам себя загнал в угол из-за нехватки знаний и не желает даже представить, что можно найти нормальное решение задачи.

золотые слова, в общем

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="" method="post" name="myform">
    <script>
        function sele() {
        if (document.getElementById('sel').selectedIndex == 0) {
        document.getElementById('s1').style.display = "block";
        } else { document.getElementById('s2').style.display = "block"; }
        }
    </script>
    <select name="MySelect" id="sel" onChange="sele()">
        <option></option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <input style="display:none;" id="s1" type="submit" name="myFirstSubmit" />
    <input style="display:none;" id="s2" type="submit" name="mySecondSubmit" />
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VNjQA/